# print preview showing NaN

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm printing the input values of my ionic app into table format and i noticed there 's a text "NaN" showing up on top of the table. is there something in the code that causes this? how do i remove it?

here's my code for the controller.js:

```
$scope.goPrint = function()
{
    cordova.plugins.printer.print('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/ionic/css/style.css" /></head><body>' + 
    '<div><img src="img/kYYXJ9o0Qk6yNSgx8ZLb_imgpsh_fullsize.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>' + 
    '<div align="left"><div class="spacer" style="height: 10px;"></div><h3 align="center">Membership Form</h3><div class="spacer" style="height: 10px;"></div>' +
    '<table class="table-border" style="width: 100%"><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' + 
    'MMID: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.mmid + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Card Number: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.cardNumber + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'First Name: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.fname + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Middle Name: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.mname + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Last Name: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.lname + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Birthday: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.bday + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Birthplace: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.birthplace + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Gender: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.gender + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Citizenship: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.citizenship + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'SSS/TIN ID: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.sssTinID + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Mobile Number: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.mobile + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Email Address: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.email + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Address: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.address + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'City: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.city + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Zipcode: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.zipcode + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Comapny Name: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.companyName + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Company Address: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.companyAddress + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Work Title: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.workTitle + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Source of Funds: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.srcFunds + '</td></tr><tr class="table-border"><td class="table-border">' +
    'Other Source of Funds: </td><td class="table-border">' + $scope.otherSrcFunds + '</td></tr>' +
    + '</table></body></html>', 'review2.html');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN, means Not a Number.. So check the calculation for the variable where you are getting NaN. One of the reason for getting NaN value can be a x/0 (where division by 0 is not allowed). Or doing math operation on string varable. If you can show where exactly you are getting this error, then we can help more.

Comment: thanks for the input. i double-checked the code and i realize there were double plus signs.